# 301 redirect from form action to URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect an URL like this one:

```
/calculate?from=london&to=paris
```

to other like this one:

```
/difference-london-paris
```

I tried this on my .htaccess file, but it doesn't work :(

```
RewriteRule ^calculate?from=(.*)&to=(.*) ^difference-$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+calculate\?from=([^&]*)&to=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ difference-%1-%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^difference-([^-]+)-([^-]+)/?$ calculate?from=$1&to=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava! There is a typo on line #6 (should be '%2' instead of '&2), but it works! :) It doesn't remove the parameters though, so it redirects to /difference-london-paris?from=london&to=paris. Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: There was not one but 2 typos. It should have been `RewriteRule ^ difference-%1-%2? [R=301,L]` Please try the edited code now.

Comment: Awesome! Not it works perfectly :) Thanks a lot! BTW, the second rewrite rule in my case redirects to a php file: difference.php?from=$1&to=$2

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to change the 2nd rule. I just wrote it by guess since there wasn't much info on that in the question :)